# PHP: Check whether array_filter deleted any entry from the array

Tags: php, array-filter

is there any way to check whether *array_filter* deleted any value from an array?

The solutions I've thought of are these ones:

```
$sample_array = ["values"];
$array_copy = $sample_array;

if (array_filter($sample_array, 'fn') === $array_copy) {
    #Some value was deleted from the array
} else {
    #The array was not modified
}
```

This one doesn't seem very efficient, as it has to copy the entire array.

```
$sample_array = ["values"];
$array_count = count($sample_array);

if (count(array_filter($sample_array, 'fn')) === $array_count) {
    #The array was not modified
} else {
    #Some value was deleted from the array
}
```

This one seems more efficient, though I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of approaching the issue.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your second solution. As long as you are not using multi-dimensional arrays this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your function to keep track of the change itself.

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$changed = 0;

$new = array_filter($array, function($e) use (&$changed) {
    $result = $e <= 2;
    if(!$result) $changed++;
    return $result;
});
```

Returns `$changed` as 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to compare two arrays.

```
if(array_diff($array_copy, $sample_array))
    echo "not same";
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought.

Comment: You still have the processing cost of iterating through the array, and greater memory usage for the result.

Comment: You still have to copy the array though, is that efficient?

Comment: The question is not about efficiency. It is about the comparison. This is a simple way using the native function. Who told you must use this? There are always many ways to the same result. As there are certainly not millions of elements, it won't face a problem.

Comment: I also provided an "efficient" and performative answer. I think this comments here lead in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure to change the state of a boolean variable:

```
$sample_array = [1,2,3,4];
$array_changed = false;

//Use closure to change $array_changed
print_r(array_filter($sample_array, function($var) use (&$array_changed) {
    $check = (!($var & 1));
    $array_changed = $array_changed?:$check;
    return $check;
}));

if ($array_changed) {
    #Some value was deleted from the array
} else {
    #The array was not modified
}
```

**[EDIT]**

This is a *simple* speedtest of your solutions compared to mine:

```
/**********************SPEEDTEST**************************/

function fn ($var) {
    return (!($var & 1));
}
$sample_array = [1,2,3,4];

$before = microtime(true);

for ($i=0 ; $i<100000 ; $i++) {

    $array_changed = false;

    //Use closure to change $array_changed
    array_filter($sample_array, function($var) use (&$array_changed) {
        $check = (!($var & 1));
        $array_changed = $array_changed?:$check;
        return $check;
    });
    if ($array_changed) {
        #Some value was deleted from the array
    } else {
        #The array was not modified
    }

}

$after = microtime(true);
echo "Using closure:      " . ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/run\n";

echo '<br>';
/*******************************************************/

$before = microtime(true);

for ($i=0 ; $i<100000 ; $i++) {

    $array_copy = $sample_array;

    if (array_filter($sample_array, 'fn') === $array_copy) {
        #Some value was deleted from the array
    } else {
        #The array was not modified
    }

}

$after = microtime(true);
echo "Using array copy:    " . ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/run\n";

echo '<br>';
/*******************************************************/

$before = microtime(true);

for ($i=0 ; $i<100000 ; $i++) {

    $array_count = count($sample_array);

    if (count(array_filter($sample_array, 'fn')) === $array_count) {
        #The array was not modified
    } else {
        #Some value was deleted from the array
    }

}

$after = microtime(true);
echo "Using array count:   " . ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/run\n";
```

The results:

```
Using closure:       9.1402053833008E-7 sec/run
Using array copy:    4.9885988235474E-7 sec/run
Using array count:   5.5881977081299E-7 sec/run
```

Maybe that helps with decision-making :)

Comment: No, that won’t work, because after filtering is done, this flag will only represent the status of the _last_ array item - if that was kept in the array, it will be true, no matter how many previous items have been removed.

Comment: $array_changed would have to only be set to true if an item is removed, but it must not be set back to false for an item that is kept.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of the removed elements, you could do something like this.

```
$sample_array = ['values', 'test'];
$removed = []; // Contains all the removed values.

$new_array = array_filter($sample_array, function($value) use (&$removed) {
    if($value == 'test') {
        $removed[] = $value; // Adds the value to the removed array.
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});

print_r($removed);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using 'count()' is IMHO the most elegant solution and, I suspect, may be a lot more efficient - you'd need to measure it. OTOH, for your consideration...

```
 function fn($arg, $mode='default')
 {
     static $matched;

     if ('default'==$mode) {
        $result=real_filter_fn($arg);
        $matched+=$result ? 1 : 0;
        return $result;
     }
     $result=$matched;
     $matched=0;
     return $result;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation and a usage example of your function would help OP a bit.

Comment: If the OP can't understand my code, then the OP has no basis for evaluating  whether it meets his/her requirements.